# Optimising microtype for variable fonts

Tags: fonts, fontspec, microtype

One can find the following passage on p. 27 of the microtype package documentation:

> Don’t use too large a value for expansion. Font expansion is a feature that is
> supposed to enhance the typographic quality of your document by producing a
> more uniform greyness of the text block (and potentially reducing the number of
> necessary hyphenations). When expanding or shrinking a font too much, the effect
> will be turned into the opposite. Expanding the fonts by more than 2%, i.e., setting
> a stretch limit of more than 20, should be justified by a typographically trained
> eye. **If you are so lucky as to be in the possession of multiple instances of a Multiple
> Master font, you may set expansion limits to up to 4%.** [Emphasis mine]

[Multiple master fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_master_fonts) have since been succeeded by OpenType 1.8, with the introduction of [variable fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_font). In contrast to ordinary fonts which come in a discrete number of weights (e.g. thin, book, regular, medium, semi-bold, bold, and black), variable fonts allow the weight to be a continuous parameter, and the same is true for other font “axes”, such as optical size and width:
[image]

Having a variable font in hand containing weight, width, and optical size axes, how should one go about configuring microtype to take advantage of these features for font expansion/shrinking?

Comment: This list of open-source variable fonts will help anyone experimenting with possible answers to your question: https://v-fonts.com/licenses/open-source

Comment: It’s probably too early for a canonical answer, because support for variable fonts is still a work in progress (see https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/120 and https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/209). By the way, there’s a font family with axes for weight and optical size which seems not to be listed at the site above: [Piazzolla](https://piazzolla.huertatipografica.com/).

Comment: I haven't really tested it (not least because luaotfload still has some problems with variable fonts), but for optical sizes and weights, the setup should be relatively straightforward by using the`fontspec` interfaces (`SizeFeatures`, `BoldFeatures` etc.), ... but since you are asking about `microtype` specifically (for which only the width axis would matter), I don't see a solution at the moment. ...

Comment: -- Hans (one of the luatex mentors) once [suggested](https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-July/006596.html) to just apply expansion and then replace the expanded glyphs with those from the variable font instances. I do not believe, however, that this would work, because while pdftex/luatex expand the glyphs linearly, this is not guaranteed with variable fonts (just like with multiple master fonts, where, eg., uppercase letters will usually be expanded more than lowercase letters...). So at least for the case of microtype I doubt that variable fonts will be usable in the foreseeable future ...

Comment: -- it either would have to be integrated into the engine itself (for pdftex, which is basically no longer developed), or the hz mechanism would have to be completely remodeled in luatex taking variable fonts into account.

Comment: @Robert Hi Robert, thank you for the explanation! Do you think Hans's suggestion might be applicable if the font itself were to be designed having microtype's expansion feature in mind from the start?