# Are there LaTeX issues or optimisations that could be nicely/best tackled at the font level?

Tags: fonts

I'm currently working on a family of fonts designed for use in formal writing and optimised in particular for use in mathematics articles, books, etc., and have recently [asked for input from mathematicians on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463883/) regarding suggestions or features such a font should have. These have focused mostly on missing symbols, problems with the current design for math (e.g. for `\mathfrak`), style preferences, among other points.

However, there's one point which I raised in the thread linked above that goes in a completely different direction than those, being instead related to LaTeX and optimisations specific to it. As this point serves as an example of the kind of thing I'm looking for in this question (i.e. a LaTeX optimisation that would be best tackled at the font level), I'll elaborate on it a bit:

> **Optimising Microtype With Fonts Having a Variable Width Axis**
>
> In a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634421/optimising-microtype-for-variable-fonts), I asked about whether it was possible to take advantage of fonts with a variable width axis to use a larger threshold for font expansion in microtype (say 4% instead of 2%). This is desirable, as it would lead to an even bigger level of interword space consistency than `microtype` already wonderfully achieves.
>
> Robert Schlicht, the developer of [`microtype`](https://ctan.org/pkg/microtype), then said the following:
>
> *Hans (one of the luatex mentors) once suggested to just apply expansion and then replace the expanded glyphs with those from the variable font instances. I do not believe, however, that this would work, because while pdftex/luatex expand the glyphs linearly, this is not guaranteed with variable fonts (just like with multiple master fonts, where, eg., uppercase letters will usually be expanded more than lowercase letters...). So at least for the case of microtype I doubt that variable fonts will be usable in the foreseeable future ...*
>
> Hearing his comment, I realised that this was a problem that could however be solved at the font level, by designing the width axis of the font solely with microtype in mind.

Besides the font, I'll also make a package for using it, like what `\usepackage{libertine}` does for Linux Libertine.

Are there other issues or optimisations specific to LaTeX that could or would be best tackled at the font or font+package level?

Comment: your question is probably too vague to answer in a site with this structure. But first are you making an opentype math font for use with unicode-math (and web browsers and MS Office etc) or a classic 8bit set of math fonts?  for opentype math there is the Math table spec, and unicode tr25 that give some basic guidelines for what a math font should cover.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was afraid of the question being too vague when asking this question, as well as the [question on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463883). I would argue the one thing that saves it from being off-topic is that any suggestions or improvements I'm able to learn through here will eventually make their way back into the community as a free font, but I do thinks this is a bit of a tricky point...

Comment: On the kind of math font, I'm planning to first develop a classic one for use with pdflatex (and in particular the arXiv, which doesn't support XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX), as I believe it doesn't support `unicode-math` (it doesn't, right?), and then *also* make an opentype math version for use with everything else.

Comment: ok so it'll be a set of fonts rather than a single one I guess. Main thing is to cover the character set of amsfonts/amssymb

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The character set is actually a very important point in the font: I plan to cover considerably more characters than `amsfonts`/`amssymb`, many of which are used in practice but require workarounds, like e.g. lowercase latin, numbers, and Greek for `\mathbb`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Incidentally, do you know of any situations where optimisations could (and maybe should) be carried at the font level, but going deeper than character sets, etc., as in the situation with microtype described above where font expansion is improved by a variable width axis? I ask because I believe it's likely you're one of the most knowledgeable people on LaTeX in the planet, and would love to hear any suggestions you might have :)

Comment: it's hard to say really especially for classic tex. If using opentype fonts there is a question about how clever you want to make font features and contextual analysis in the font, but for pdftex you just have tfm metrics so there is really nothing to optimise you just can specify the glyph dimensions

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, thanks! Moving from classic tex to its extensions, do you know of any other packages for which one finds a similar situation such as microtype, where optimisations at the font level are beneficial?

Comment: not really, but as I say I think the question is too vague to answer, you are basically asking if any package could make use of any font feature you might add.

Comment: Note that there is a limit to the number of maths fonts you can use as such in a document compiled with classic fonts, as well as a limited number of characters per font. So unless there are other uses for them, you want to consider what it makes sense to create. Just adding characters won't necessarily do away with the need for workarounds, for example.

Comment: @cfr I haven't yet started development on the math counterpart of the font, so I wasn't aware of this. I really hope there are some hacks available for getting around this (even if really ugly/messy ones), since it really screws with the idea of the math font having an extremely comprehensive set of symbols, like `\mathbb` for numbers, lowercase Latin, Greek and Cyrillic =/

Comment: @Emily The solution is to use `math-unicode` with Lua/XeTeX. You can get particular symbols without using up one of your fonts, but, as I understand it, the total number of maths fonts is determined by the underlying TeX. So there is a hard limit on the number of characters provided specifically by maths fonts with non-unicode engines. The hacks are probably the workarounds you were hoping to avoid :(.

Comment: For classic TeX, it is easier to support fonts which follow standard encodings and (ideally) glyph names. Not sure what you're thinking for text, but for classic text and maths fonts, note that a bunch of decisions get made by the support package and not by the font. Other decisions are somewhat set independently of both. (There are some sneaky things you can do, but I won't mention those in front of @DavidCarlisle.)

Comment: @cfr I'm planning on also making a package for the font (something like `\usepackage{darwin}`, like how Linux Libertine has `\usepackage{libertine}`), so I hope I can at least push the hacks and sneaky things under the rug, so the end user ends up not having to deal with them. My biggest concern with relying on `math-unicode` via Lua/XeTeX is that the arXiv doesn't support compilation with them yet, so not providing support for pdflatex would be a huge deal =/

Comment: [The TUGboat fonts section](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html#CatTAGFonts) is a good place to start; [these](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb44-2/tb137vieth-otmath.pdf) [two](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb44-2/tb137sundqvist-otmath.pdf) recent articles seem particularly relevant. I'd also recommend looking at the [Stix (Two)](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/blob/master/README.md) and [New CM](https://texdoc.org/serve/newcm/0) fonts; they both appear to cover most (if not all) if the issues discussed in the MO thread.

Comment: @MaxChernoff Thank you so much for the pointers and resources, these seem super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This answer is unworthy of the bounty, because it is very limited in scope.

Yes, there are some font-level optimizations. Specifically in the case of running text (not math symbols), be sure to limit the height and depth of character designs.

If you are designing with cubic splines (OpenType with PostScript outlines, not TrueType with quadratic splines) and your font grid is 1000 units per em (standard for OpenType):

A "well behaved" font has its tallest text character no taller than 840 grid units above baseline, and its deepest text character no deeper than 260 grid units below baseline. Characters used in math expressions and diagrams (not running text) do not need to comply. For running text, in Latin-1 plus curly quotes and similar typography, the tallest character will be an uppercase letter with diacritical mark, and the deepest letter will be among gjpqy. But beware, if you also use slashes or bars in text. Also beware if you use superscripts (such as footnote markers) that are in raised boxes, instead of called directly from the font as OpenType features.

Reason: The LaTeX `\strut` is `0.7\baselineskip` above baseline, and `0.3\baselineskip` below baseline. Some (non-TeX) programs use a default, tight line spacing of `1.2em`. If you choose this, then a "well-behaved" font will fit within the strut at tight line spacing, leaving `0.1em` gap between lines.

Many ordinary text fonts, used for book publishing (to paper), are "well-behaved". Some, not all, LaTeX fonts are "well-behaved, or nearly so. A few fonts (such as `fbb`) are far from "well-behaved", and can cause line spacing issues if not used carefully.

But if your only concern is for math expressions, then you do not need to care about any of the above.

Comment: Optimising the font for text is one of my main objectives; I'll be sure to follow this specification, thank you so much for taking the time to write an answer and let me know about it!

Comment: I know you asked me not to give you the bounty, but it's about to expire and I don't like the idea of it just disappearing into the nothingness forever (and besides, I'm really thankful for your suggestion! =). Feel free to use these silly points to put a bounty on a question (or more) you find nice, or just have them absorbed into yours forever.

Comment: Thanks! Another point: If your usage situation may require non-numeric footnote markers (asterisk, dagger, etc.) then be sure to create characters for them, assigned to the superscripts (sups) OpenType feature.

Comment: Thank _you_ for the feedback! To be sure I won't forget to implement this, I've noted it here: [https://github.com/topological-modular-forms/Darwin-Typeface/issues/41](https://github.com/topological-modular-forms/Darwin-Typeface/issues/41). (The repository is currently private, but this will change soon)